# Ionic Cordova POST the call send adding \ in data

Tags: json, cordova, http, ionic-framework, ionic4

i'm using cordova http plugin While sending the encryption data. the our data is contain /. While receiving in server the every froward / the add the extra back slash due to this we are getting the problem in decryption.
ex

`{"Metadata":"gIVZ3zqYCjTUMGgkUfr/pJc5N+X6X5VRJr/cXrgSeEBGjEgPmTU+3iNe+dqp/xRi2NyiYG4lxr7UXazKjmxElJypwnZGxYVB8bX0PzDccS4=","MetaInfo":"YPwpLWjttEqv3eA4itiBFZfqKsVVoQP7bFRfTxdH2QtQaqdHLPjpEa/I7SuLSGPsGm3nVL6zsy3PmOk1PfnNUvsyJUMUDrMm0gPX2sPIhnm4TMbfEm/Vk/Opm86bM304f8lsdQa8evG+DFNJTAy64f4ZJGRP4YZuC7rxArA3Y53c9kfiw9vn65kyFgXT4MrkIqZrrrRDp1OVsHOy75+N28cGOWja1Guvch0uKQzGrreCOpzyWSgojYpIpywIPM4z1iuuGC+/G/LJtZjsSVmHVFgNJoEcfDJ5FyYA28FtobLZKRzGBoTbVfVd9mi2YYmlYgb6E2ko57jBKmwiRZMUTw=="}`

`{"Metadata":"gIVZ3zqYCjTUMGgkUfr\/pJc5N+X6X5VRJr\/cXrgSeEBGjEgPmTU+3iNe+dqp\/xRi2NyiYG4lxr7UXazKjmxElJypwnZGxYVB8bX0PzDccS4=","MetaInfo":"YPwpLWjttEqv3eA4itiBFZfqKsVVoQP7bFRfTxdH2QtQaqdHLPjpEa\/I7SuLSGPsGm3nVL6zsy3PmOk1PfnNUvsyJUMUDrMm0gPX2sPIhnm4TMbfEm\/Vk\/Opm86bM304f8lsdQa8evG+DFNJTAy64f4ZJGRP4YZuC7rxArA3Y53c9kfiw9vn65kyFgXT4MrkIqZrrrRDp1OVsHOy75+N28cGOWja1Guvch0uKQzGrreCOpzyWSgojYpIpywIPM4z1iuuGC+\/G\/LJtZjsSVmHVFgNJoEcfDJ5FyYA28FtobLZKRzGBoTbVfVd9mi2YYmlYgb6E2ko57jBKmwiRZMUTw=="}`

Comment: It appears to be escaping your slashes

Comment: Have your server parse it. In node.js / JavaScript, parsing it removes the escaping slashes.